# kSecUseAuthenticationUISkip how to use it

Tags: ios, security, keychain

I want to add an item to secItemAdd with following access control

```
SecAccessControlRef sacObject = SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                             kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock,
                                                             /*kecAccessControlTouchIDAny | */kSecAccessControlApplicationPassword, &error);
```

So it basically asking password for adding item to keychain, that is perfect but when I want to access this Item I want to skip UI authentication and somwhow I wnat to provide the password manually with use of kSecUseAuthenticationUISkip.

Answer (score 3):

As per Apple's documentation on the `kSecUseAuthenticationUISkip` constant (https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/ksecuseauthenticationuiskip?language=objc)

> Silently skip any items that require user authentication. Only use this value with the `SecItemCopyMatching` function.

So it's not for selectively skipping the authentication, but rather for skipping items that require authentication

Now for your case when you want to secure access to the keychain with an app provided password, when calling `SecItemAdd` you'd have to use the `kSecUseAuthenticationContext` key set to a `LAContext` instance of type `LACredentialTypeApplicationPassword` that holds the password you ask from your user in conjunction with the `kSecAccessControlApplicationPassword` in the object you pass to the `kSecAttrAccessControl` key.

Here'a an article that it explains it with an example that I think it fits your use case pretty well: http://collinbstuart.github.io/lessons/2015/11/04/keychain_entropy

Comment: The link mentioned seems to be broken. But I found another example which is well written  
  
https://macbirdie.net/2016/03/app-pwd

Comment: This particular article seems to have moved here: https://kolinsturt.github.io/lessons/2015/11/04/keychain-entropy